# how to retrieve data from map for Listtile in flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-listview, listtile

i want to receive data from a map i received from sharedpreference.

the Data looks like this:

{2022-04-08 15:49:41.864929: 1234567, 2022-04-08 15:49:55.392684: 1234567, 2022-04-08 15:50:17.168655: 1234567, 2022-04-08 15:50:39.263044: 1234567}

The date is they key, and the numbers the value.
Now i need to display all 4 keys and the values in 4 listtiles.
How is this possible?
I am really new in flutter.

````
  _saveData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(DateTime.now().toString(), '1234567');
  }

  _clearData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.clear();
    print('Daten gelöscht');
  }



  _loadData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final keys = prefs.getKeys();

    final prefsMap = Map<String, dynamic>();
    for(String key in keys) {
      prefsMap[key] = prefs.get(key);
    }

    print(prefsMap);
  }```
````

Comment: Iterate over all the keys with this sharePreferences function `getKeys()`, then it will return a Set<String> value with all the keys, iterate over all of them with forEach to then store each value and key in a variable List<Map<String, String>>, then do a map to it to transform each value into a ListTile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I included a rough example here. 
You can check out the demo at https://dartpad.dev/087d5cfc1044c8ce742a0c5c7147940f

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // An example of using Future to return Map<String, dynamic>
    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _loadData() async {
      Map<String, dynamic> dataFromSharedPref = {};

      // A task that needs some time to load e.g. Getting data from SharedPreference
      // TODO: Change this part to load from your SharedPreference
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        dataFromSharedPref = {
          "2022-04-08 15:49:41.864929": "1234567",
          "2022-04-08 15:49:55.392684": "1234567"
        };
      });

      return dataFromSharedPref;
    }

    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _loadData(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            // Show loading when there is no data
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            // Build the list when data is received
            var myData = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: myData.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  String key = myData.keys.elementAt(index);
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Key: $key'),
                    subtitle: Text('Value: ${myData[key]}'),
                  );
                });
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: That works fine with the given Textdata. But my problem is, i cant access the prefsMap from inside the loadData()????? Other solutions not working because i cant set the async outside to my code :-(

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do? So we can have more idea on how to help you. Because I am not sure what you meant by outside your code

Comment: My english is not that good. My problem is that i cant access the variable prefsMap from loadData because it is a async method. The prefMap from the loadData is not available outside the loadData function ....

Comment: @romu2000 I edited my answer. If you think the solution solved your problem, please accept my answer :)

Comment: This is exactly what i need, but i am not able to get the Data from prefsmap from the _loadData() function into dataFromSharedPref. I hope you can help me again...Sorry

Comment: Maybe I'll give you some more insights here. For your _loadData function, simply change your function to return a `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>` and then in the end of your _loadData function, just add a `return prefsMap` and it should be working.